# Android google keyboard won't install

Tags: gboard

Google released their google keyboard as an app in the market but I cannot install it. The error is "Application already exists". I am on a Att Note 1 (touchwiz\unrooted). No other keyboards are installed. Does anyone know how to install this?

edit: Despite this error message, the only option I have in my keyboard settings is "samsung keyboard"

Comment: It comes as part of the stock android install, mine updated last night (note the word updated, I never installed it).

Comment: And before you ask why then it's put on Play at all: 1) to be updated to devices already having a previous version of it, as it also happens with the *Google Play* app itself, and b) for those devices whipping with a different one (e.g. devices from LG).

Comment: AOSP keyboard from Play store requires ICS upwards, just something to keep in mind!

Answer (score 1):

You may change package name and install it as separate user app

Links for version 4.0.21203.1613964 apk with already changed package name and additional symbols: [source (russian forum with registration)](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=469533&view=findpost&p=35048430) or [mirrors](https://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/0JXPMBME/GoogleKeyboard_4.0.21203.1613964_A_mod_symb_noroot.apk_links)

Screenshot of additional symbols:

[image]